# Concurrent Random Number Generation in Library Code

Tags: c++, random, concurrency

I am writing some library code in C++, and I need to generate some random numbers. 
I created the function below to generate a per thread generator and initialize it using data from std::random_device. If I call it in a single-threaded environment, everything seems to work.  However, if I call it concurrently I seem to get repeated elements.

```
inline std::mt19937_64& initialize_mt_generator() { 

    constexpr size_t state_size = std::mt19937_64::state_size * 
        std::mt19937_64::word_size / 32;

    std::vector<uint32_t> random_data(state_size);
    thread_local std::random_device source{}; 
    std::generate(random_data.begin(), random_data.end(), std::ref(source));
    thread_local std::seed_seq seeds(random_data.begin(), random_data.end());
    thread_local static std::mt19937_64 engine(seeds);

   return engine; 

}
```

The way that I am using it is this function is in a library, that I use to make a Python extension. The parallel code is entirely in Python where I use the multiprocessing module.  I am not sure that that matters through.

Comment: Each thread constructs its `std::random_device` with the same seed.

Comment: `std::random_device` isn't guaranteed to be non deterministic.  Do a couple `std::random_device{}()` in a row and see if they give yoiu the same value for each.  If they do you know it isn't non deterministic.

Comment: Python’s multiprocessing module isn’t using threads, it’s launching a new _process_ for each worker. If you’re on Unix, it defaults to launching that new process by forking the parent. If you’ve already initialized the RNG before that happens, every worker gets a copy of the same RNG state.

Comment: There is no need to use thread_local attribute on automatic variables

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not a good test. First of all, a non-deterministic generator can return the same number an arbitrary number of times in a row (if it couldn't, that would be a pattern indicating that it wasn't really random). Second, a deterministic implementation of random_device is still likely to be pseudo-random, so it won't necessarily be easy to spot patterns in its output.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If it is deterministic then `std::random_device{}()` should always produce the same result.  If it isn't then there is a chance you would get the same number multiple times in a row but that odds of that happening are pretty astronomical if you do it several times.

Comment: Which platform are you using? `std::random_device` is allowed to be deterministic and it looks like MinGW's implementation is deterministic: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/338/

Comment: @NathanOliver: [rand.device]/2: "If implementation limitations prevent generating nondeterministic random numbers, the implementation may
employ a random number engine." If you want to know whether it's non-deterministic, call its `entropy()` member function. That will return 0.0 if it's deterministic, and a non-zero value if it's non-deterministic.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yes, and calling a default constructed random generator always produces the same results.  So `std::random_device{}` gives you a default constructed PRNG and then `()` gets the first value which should always be the same.  It's not any different from `std::mt19937{}()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Nothing says it's necessarily default constructed. It could (for example) use the strategy that was common with `srand`, and seed from a time-stamp.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  I think random_device is not deterministic here.

Comment: @abarnert I had wondered in Python and C++ concurrency was conflicting. Is there a way to reinitialize the state when a new process is created? Should I use a thread_local singleton?

Comment: @sangrey `thread_local` anything isn't going to help with separate processes. If you fork a copy, it's still a copy whether it was thread-local or not. If you have separate instances constructed in each process, they're separate (even if global/static) without needing to be thread-local.

Comment: Options include: (a) make each process create its own RNG object (possibly from the Python side), (b) use `spawn` instead of `fork` in the Python multiprocessing module, (c) keep a static map of PID to RNG objects instead of a static thread-local RNG object, (d) just make it not `static` in the first place. (That means callers can't just call the `initialize` function again and expect to get back the same one they got last time if they're on the same thread, but… do you actually need that?)

Comment: Anyway, this really isn't about Python vs. C++ concurrency. If you use threads in Python, they're threads in C++. If you use child processes in Python, they're child processes in C++. You'd have the same problem in a pure-C++ program that used `fork` instead of `thread::thread` and then tried to use `thread_local` as if it were multithreaded.

Comment: Just creating independent copies of the the RNG object does not help. I did it on the C++ side. Does that mean you cannot use a RNG in multiple processes without explicitly controlling the RNG creation from Python?